# Resourcemanager is returning same resource, although CultureInfo is specified

Tags: c#, dll, globalization, embedded-resource, resourcemanager

A very simple thing, and I can't get it to work. I want to globalise my dll thus I'm using resource files + the ResourceManager.

I call the resourcemanager like this:

```
var p = new ResourceManager("Appname.Default", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Get the strings like this

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(p.GetString("greeting"));
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(p.GetString("greeting", new CultureInfo("nl")));
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(p.GetString("greeting", new CultureInfo("nl-NL")));
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(p.GetString("greeting", new CultureInfo("en")));
```

And it returns 4 times the same string. My files are called

```
Default.resx 
Default.en.resx 
Default.nl.resx 
Default.nl-NL.resx
```

All file settings are the same, but as mentioned - only the resource in the Default file is used.

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: Are the .resx file actually getting compiled into satellite assemblies?  Look in the bin\Debug folder and look for subdirectories with names en, nl and nl-NL.

Comment: Try to get the translations via `Default.ResourceManager.GetString`. Most likely the resource manager you're creating gets some wrong parameter(s).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a few ways of using resource files, one of which is using `.resx` files. These files get localized automatically, based on the value of `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`. The default `.resx` file gets compiled into the assembly it is part of (for example your main executable), while the localized resources (`Default.nl-NL.resx`) get compiled into their own directory (based on the culture identifier, `nl-NL` in this case) into an assembly, called `<AssemblyName>.resources.dll`.

Addressing values from those resources is as easy as `<ResourceName>.<KeyName>`, for example `Default.Greeting`. To test it, you change the culture, using:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
Console.WriteLine(Default.Greeting);

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL");
Console.WriteLine(Default.Greeting);
```

Which will output

```
Hello
Hallo
```

On program startup, the UI Culture is set to the culture of the computer it's running on, so you won't have to specify the language yourself to always present the localized resources. So, `.resx` files seem the way to go.

When using the `ResourceManager` from `var p = new ResourceManager("Appname.Default", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`, you will have to read `.resources` files. If there is no (in your case) `Appname.Default.resources` file, the `p.GetString` will fail. So I guess you have created one `.resources` file earlier, but haven't converted the localized `.resx` files to `.resources` files.

If you want to use the ResourceManager to be able to specify the culture, you can use:

```
Default.ResourceManager.GetString("Greeting", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: Thanks - I don't know why I didn't just use Resources.Default. Must be the weekend!

Comment: @CodeCaster could you please take a look at my question please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070892/resources-dont-load-current-culture

Comment: My issue was not in the code but I did not deploy the dlls within folders such as `\en-US` or `\pt-BR`.  Just deploying the dlls withing these folders solved my problem.