# Resources don't load current culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to change the culture on a `ASP.NET Web API 2`
but I can't figure out which function to override

I have tried `ExecuteAsync` and `Initialize` but the application uses the English resources no matter what.

This is how I set the culture

```
        protected void SetCulture(string cultureName)
        {
            // Validate culture name
            cultureName = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(cultureName);

            // Modify current thread's cultures            
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        }

        protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
             if (controllerContext.Request.Headers.AcceptLanguage != null &&
                controllerContext.Request.Headers.AcceptLanguage.Count > 0)
             {
                 string language = controllerContext.Request.Headers.AcceptLanguage.First().Value;

                 SetCulture(language);
             }
            base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        }
```

and here the resources is always in English. I have put a watch on `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and it says `fr`

```
        private void SendConfirmationEmail(string userId)
        {
            ...
            UserManager.SendEmail(userId,
                Resources.Resources.ConfirmAccount,
                Resources.Resources.PleaseClickToConfirmAccount
                                                + callbackUrl);

        }
```

How can we set the current culture?

**EDIT**

I have the same problem after setting the culture in the `Global.asax`

```
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpRequest currentRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            if (currentRequest.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Accept-Language"))
            {
                string culture = currentRequest.Headers["Accept-Language"].ToString();
                SetCulture(culture);
            }
        }
```

The `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` equals `fr`. I don't understand why the resources are still in English!

**EDIT 2**

I created resource files in the properties of the Web API project and now it works.

So the problem is with the resources.dll.

I don't understand why the API can't choose the good resources file with the resources.dll. Maybe the resources.fr.resx is not with the dll.

Comment: Are you using Web Hosting Web API?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Web Hosting Web API. Could you explain please

Comment: Are you hosting it in IIS side by side with an ASP.NET Web App?

Comment: Yes, I have a ASP.NET MVC 5 project also on IIS. I'm currently on localhost.

Comment: Set the culture at protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in the Global.asax e see if changes something.

Comment: I was looking at this earlier but I couldn't find an example. So there's no override to do for this?

Comment: Well if you weren't hosting it on Web App or if you want to have some fun, you should create a delegating handle to set the culture. The delegating handle will execute early than the controller in the pipeline.

Comment: put `base.Initialize()` before setting the culture, because I have a feeling that sets the thread back to english.

Comment: @Silvermind Unfortunately I still have the same problem

Comment: Can you show us how you implement the resources?

Comment: I did a resources library which works already in my ASP.NET MVC project and I added the reference to the API. Then I call the resources like this Resources.Resources.ConfirmAccount like in the example in my question. Is there anything else to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

When you compile a project with resources, it creates a folder for each culture with a `.dll`

So I had to copy those folders too. Not only `resources.dll` because this is only the default language. That's why no matter what was the culture, my resources were in English.

So to use `resources.dll`

1. you have to import that reference
2. copy all your culture folders in the bin folder with all the `.dll`

Note: you don't have to add a reference for each culture, only your default one.