# c# Language.resx doesn't work when I install my compiled application

Tags: c#, resources, resx, currentculture

I have an winform c# application that can change between multiple languages. When execute my application in visual studio the language changes well, but when I compile the application and install it in my computer it does nothing.

This is my code to change the current language:

```
public void ChangeCurrentLanguage(string selectedLanguage)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(selectedLanguage);
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(selectedLanguage);
}
```

And this is my code to get some strings from the resx of the current language:

```
ChangeCurrentLanguage("es-ES");
string downloadSucess = LanguageResx.ClientLanguage.game_DownloadSucess;
```

As I said works well in visual studio, but when I install it into my computer it does nothing.

I have all of my different languages in resx files and I just change the current language
[image: resx image]

And I have a setup for the user to install my application.

[image: setup image]

[image: Dll 2]

[image: Dll 3]

[image: Dll 4]

[image: Dll 5]

**POSIBLE SOLUTION**

[Posible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070892/resources-dont-load-current-culture), the only problem is that the guy in the answer talk about using resources.dll and I dont have that dll or dont know how to get it and use it to make it work.

Comment: @mjwills I will show you with images

**In visual studio:**

spanish: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uPhD.png

english: https://i.stack.imgur.com/chQVr.png


**In my compiled application already installed in my computer:**

spanish: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHEy8.png

english: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfYIE.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I'm just stupid, I only have to move the folders of the resx translations to my setup folder